# Taking the fractional part of a sum with an integer

Tags: analytic-number-theory

In Hildebrand and Tenenbaum's [Integers without large prime factors](http://www.numdam.org/article/JTNB_1993__5_2_411_0.pdf), I've come across the equation
$$\Psi(x,y)=x\rho(u)\bigg\{1+O\bigg(\frac{log(u+1)}{log\ y}\bigg)\bigg\}$$
My understanding of the braces here is that they take the fractional part of a number e.g. $\{3.7\}=0.7$ and so wouldn't $\{1+k\}=\{k\}$? I assume something about the big-Oh part gives this meaning, but I don't understand why adding one has any effect here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it happens, no, they just mean large brackets by the curly braces. This is confusing, but happens with some regularity in older analytic number theory texts (see e.g. Apostol's classic texts; they're riddled with places in which $\{\dots\}$ means fractional part or just grouping, depending on (to the beginner very vague) context).

Comment: Oh that is very confusing. I found the same notation used infrequently in [Granville's](https://dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/msrire.pdf) 2008 paper. It looks very intentional since he uses curly braces in the same equation (1.8), but the usual parentheses in the similar equation (1.17). Is there any reason for that or is it completely arbitrary?

Comment: I don't know enough about historical typesetting to say if there's a deep reason, but in practice it often (but not always) happens when there is (a) an $O(\dots)$ term inside the grouping, and especially (but again not always!) when (b) that error term has a fraction or something making the parentheses big.

Comment: As an example, on p. 58 of Apostol's Intro to analytic number theory, there is $\sum_{q \leq x/d} 1 = \frac{x}{d} + O(1)$, derived earlier, and when substituted into a larger computation on the next line, it gets decorated with $\{ \dots \}$ for no reason other than some brackets were needed---it's the same quantity.

Comment: If I had to guess, in this particular case, I'd venture Hildebrand, Tenenbaum, and in particular Granville use the curly braces for this particular result only because de Bruijn did in the original paper they're citing. As to why de Bruijn did it: my guess (but it's only a guess) is that they took $\{ \dots \}$ to mean "something involving an error", because they seem consistent about using it for that purpose.